# C++ do while keeps repeating

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int getTreeNo(int);
int getSpeciesCode(int);
float getDbh(float);
int getTotHt(int);
int getTotHt(int);
double calcTotVol(double[], double[], float, int);

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int treeNo = 0;
    int speciesCode = 0;
    string speciesDesc[6] = {};
    float dbh = 0.00;
    int totalHt = 0;
    double totalVol = 0.00;
    int Species[6] = {};
    double b0[6] = {};
    double b1[6] = {};
    int noTrees = 0;

    treeNo = getTreeNo(treeNo);
    /* Gets number of trees for calculations*/
    speciesCode = getSpeciesCode(speciesCode);
    /* Get Species code from user*/
    dbh = getDbh(dbh);
    /* get DBH from user*/
    totalHt = getTotHt(totalHt);
    /*Gets tree height from user*/
    totalVol = calcTotVol(b0, b1, dbh, totalHt);
    /* Calculates values */

    /* All constants and variables
        int treeNo;
        int speciesCode;
        string speciesDesc[6];
        float dbh;
        int totalHt;
        double totalVol;
        int Species[6];
        double b0[6];
        double b1[6];
        int noTrees;
        double avgTotVol;
    */
    if (speciesCode = 11) {
        speciesDesc[0] = "Loblolly Pine";
    } else if (speciesCode = 12) {
        speciesDesc[1] = "White Pine";
    } else if (speciesCode = 13) {
        speciesDesc[2] = "Red Pine";
    } else if (speciesCode = 21) {
        speciesDesc[3] = "White Oak";
    } else if (speciesCode = 22) {
        speciesDesc[4] = "Red Oak";
    } else if (speciesCode = 23) {
        speciesDesc[5] = "Other Oak";
    }

    Species[0] = 11;
    Species[1] = 12;
    Species[2] = 13;
    Species[3] = 21;
    Species[4] = 22;
    Species[5] = 23;

    if (speciesCode = 11) {
        b0[0] = 1.2446;
    } else if (speciesCode = 12) {
        b0[1] = 0.000;
    } else if (speciesCode = 13) {
        b0[2] = 2.0822;
    } else if (speciesCode = 21) {
        b0[3] = .7316;
    } else if (speciesCode = 22) {
        b0[4] = 1.6378;
    } else if (speciesCode = 23) {
        b0[5] = .7554;
    }
    if (speciesCode = 11) {
        b1[0] = .002165;
    } else if (speciesCode = 12) {
        b1[1] = .002364;
    } else if (speciesCode = 13) {
        b1[2] = .002046;
    } else if (speciesCode = 21) {
        b1[3] = .001951;
    } else if (speciesCode = 22) {
        b1[4] = .002032;
    } else if (speciesCode = 23) {
        b1[5] = .002174;
    }
    totalVol = b0[6] + b1[6] * pow(dbh, 2) * totalHt;

    for (i = 0; i < treeNo; i++) {
        cout << "Tree Number " << i + 1 << ": " << speciesCode << dbh << totalHt
             << speciesDesc[6] << b0[6] << b1[6] << totalVol;
    }
}

/************************************************************************************************
 * *************/
int getTreeNo(int treeNo) {
    do {
        cout << "Please enter the number of trees :" << endl;
        cin >> treeNo;
        if ((treeNo <= 0) || (treeNo > 999)) {
            cout << "ERROR!!!,You cannot have more then999 entries" << endl;
        }
    } while ((treeNo <= 0) || (treeNo > 999));
    return treeNo;
}

int getSpeciesCode(int speciesCode) {

    do {
        cout << "Please enter your Species Code";
        cin >> speciesCode;

    } while ((speciesCode != 11) || (speciesCode != 12) ||
             (speciesCode != 13) || (speciesCode != 21) ||
             (speciesCode != 22) || (speciesCode != 23));

    cout << "ERROR!!!,That information does not exist wthin our system" << endl;

    return speciesCode;
}

float getDbh(float dbh) {
    do {
        cout << "Please enter the DBH of the tree, The DBH must be greter then "
                "and equal to  five and less then 50.6" << endl;
        cin >> dbh;
        if ((dbh < 5) || (dbh > 50.6)) {
            cout << "ERROR!!!, The DBH must be greter then and equal to five "
                    "and less then 50.6" << endl;
        }
    } while ((dbh < 5) || (dbh > 50.6));
    return dbh;
}

int getTotHt(int totalHt) {
    do {
        cout << "Please enter the height of the tree" << endl;
        cin >> totalHt;
        if ((totalHt < 24) || (totalHt > 160)) {
            cout << "ERROR!!!, Please enter a height thats not larger then "
                    "160, but greater then 24" << endl;
        }

    } while (totalHt < 24 || totalHt > 160);
    { return totalHt; }
}
double calcTotVol(double array[], double array1[], float dbh, int totalHt) {
    double totalVol;

    totalVol = array[6] + array1[6] * pow(dbh, 2) * totalHt;

    return totalVol;
}
```

can anyone help me my speciesCode function keeps looping and will not accept my input actually I do not believe any function is accepting it I have worked for hours to try to figure out why and am stuck

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition in this while statement will never ever be false, and your loop will never exit.  In order for it to be false, `speciesCode` has to have more than 1 value at a time.

```
while((speciesCode != 11) || (speciesCode != 12) || (speciesCode != 13) || ...)
```

You probably want to keep repeating until you get a valid code.  In that case use `&&`

```
while((speciesCode != 11) && (speciesCode != 12) && (speciesCode != 13) && ...)
```

Comment: @CaseyNelms that will get it to stop looping eventually, but it looks like you actually want `while((speciesCode!=11) &&`

Comment: that fixed it, but it still does it on the height

Comment: I fixed the height but it keeps crashing after that could it be my calcTotVol function? sorry I am so lost this is my final its its tearing me to pieces

Comment: @CaseyNelms The valid indexes in an array with six items is 0 through 5. Accessing index 6, the seventh item, is undefined and may cause very strange things to happen.

Comment: oh my i feel stupid, but it keeps showing an unhandled exception and the number is way off

Comment: @CaseyNelms is it a particular kind of exception such as null pointer exception or index out of bounds exception?

Comment: cout<< "Tree Number " << i + 1 << ": " << speciesCode << dbh << totalHt << speciesDesc[5]<< b0[5]<<b1[5]<<totalVol;

Comment: i fixed the exception but this line is giving me problems it does not want to show the description or the b0 or b1 correct